# Construct a function $f \in C [0,1]$ satisfying $\int_{0}^{\frac {1}{2}}f - \int_{\frac {1}{2}}^1 f = 1$ and $\sup_{t \in [0,1] } |f (t)| = c $

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Given $ c > 1$, what function $f \in C [0,1]$ exists satisfying $$\int_{0}^{\frac {1}{2}}f - \int_{\frac {1}{2}}^1 f = 1$$  and $\sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)| = c$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $\epsilon < 1/2$ consider the function $f_\epsilon$ defined by 
$f_\epsilon(x) = c$ if $x < \frac 12 - \epsilon$

$f_\epsilon(x) = c - \frac c\epsilon \cdot (x-(\frac 12 -\epsilon))$ if $\frac 12 - \epsilon \leq x \leq \frac 12 + \epsilon $

$f_\epsilon(x) = -c$ otherwise.

Then : 
$\int_{0}^{\frac {1}{2}}f - \int_{\frac {1}{2}}^1 f = c(1-\frac \epsilon 2)$, so you just need to take $\epsilon=2*(1-\frac 1c)$

(This only works with $c \leq 2$, otherwise just do the same with $c_2 = min(c,2)$)

Edit : I just noticed that you want the sup to be equal to c (and not just lesser or equal to c), so you got to work a little bit more here, but you can use the same idea that I described here.